# Getting a "Subscript out of range" error, and I don't know whats wrong. (I'm kind of new to vba)

Tags: vba, excel

This is my code:

```
Private Sub New_User_Create_Click()
CreateUsername_L = LCase(Create_User_Text.Text)
For Each ws In Worksheets
    If (Worksheets(CreateUsername_L).Name <> "") Then
        MsgBox "Username is already taken! Try again!"
        Create_User_Text.Text = ""
        NewUser.Hide
        Exit For
    Else
        Dim work As Worksheet
        With ThisWorkbook
        Set worksheetname = .Sheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
        worksheetname.Name = CreateUsername_L
        On Error Resume Next
        Create_User_Text.Text = ""
        NewUser.Hide
        [B1].Value = (UserName + "'s Personal Profile")
        Exit For

        End With

    End If
Next ws   
End Sub
```

If you could help me with this it would be much appreciated
(also the error only occurs when the condition is not met e.g there is no sheet with the same name as "CreateUsername_L". When the condition is met the message box with "Username is already taken..." shows up so its only when the condition is not met when this error occurs)

Comment: Which line does the error occur on?

Answer (score 2):

You can't test for the existance of the worksheet name like you're trying to do.  The 'Subscript out of range' error is looking for that worksheet name and if it can't find it then you get your error.  You can write a function to test for the existence of a name and use that instead.  Here's mine:

```
Public Function doesSheetNameExist(inputName As String) As Boolean
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    On Error GoTo ErrorCatch

    Set ws = Thisworkbook.Worksheets(inputName)
    'if no error here then worksheet exists
    doesSheetNameExist= True

CloseFunction:
    Exit Function
ErrorCatch:
    doesSheetNameExist= False
    Resume CloseFunction
End Function
```

This handles the error within the function.  Alternatively you could loop through each worksheet and test the name.

You'd then replace your line

```
If (Worksheets(CreateUsername_L).Name <> "") Then
```

with

```
If doesSheetNameExist(CreateUsername_L) Then
```